# Is it possible to parse an INI file with comments and edit it?

Tags: php, parsing, ini, php-ini

I have created a form,I read from a INI file and show its values in the form.
Now I want to edit that file.

So I show values in text box and let the user edit the file.

Now I am using INI Library to write my files, but my code changes the structure of INI file, also it remove the comments.

Is it possible that when I write to the file only those value is changed and other things like comments and Section remain as it is ?

This is my code:

```
$CFG_file = $this->data['file_data'] = parse_ini_file("CFG/fms.cfg" ,true);


        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {   

            //var_dump($_POST);
            $data_file = $this->parameter_m->array_from_post(array('VAL1','VAL2','InMedia','VAL','VAL','VAL5','VAL3'));

            $this->load->helper('file');
            $file = "CFG/fms.cfg";
            $this->load->library('ini');
            $ini = new INI($file);
            $ini->write($file, $data_file );    
        }
```

And the library code that writes file :

```
function write($file = NULL, $file_content = array(), $sections = FALSE) {
    $this->file_content = (!empty($file_content)) ? $file_content : $this->file_content;
    $this->file = ($file) ? $file : $this->file;
    $this->sections = $sections;
    $content = NULL;

    if ($this->sections) {
        foreach ($this->file_content as $section => $file_content) {
            $content .= '[' . $section . ']' . PHP_EOL;
            foreach ($file_content as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    foreach ($val as $v) {
                        $content .= $key . '[]=' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : $v ) . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } elseif (empty($val)) {
                    $content .= $key . '=' . PHP_EOL;
                } else {
                    $content .= $key . '=' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : $val ) . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
            $content .= PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->file_content as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                foreach ($val as $v) {
                    $content .= $key . '[] = ' . (is_numeric($v) ? $v : '"' . $v . '"') . PHP_EOL;
                }
            } elseif (empty($val)) {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $content .= $key . ' = ' . (is_numeric($val) ? $val : '"' . $val . '"') . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    return (($handle = fopen($this->file, 'w+')) && fwrite($handle, trim($content)) && fclose($handle)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

And this is my file :

```
    []
VAL1= 0.0.0.0
VAL2= 5070

;media settings

;ON/OFF/AUTO
VAL3= OFF

VAL4= 8000 
VAL5= 4000
VAL6= 360

;Transport settings

;ON/OFF
VAL7= OFF
```

When i execute my code this becomes  :

```
VAL1= "0.0.0.0"
VAL2 = 5071
VAL3 = 
VAL4 = 8000
VAL5 = 4000
VAL6 = 360
VAL7 = "ON"
```

Comment: Not with `parse_ini_file()`. You'll have to write your own parser (it's a fairly simple format anyway) or find a third-party one.

Comment: I am not that much expert, that i could write a parser, but if you have any idea please guide me or let me know any other third party know parser if there is any @ÁlvaroGonzález